# Symmetries for an inertial frame

Tags: classical-mechanics

According to Noether's theorem, a symmetry of space-time w.r.t. an observer, will yield a corresponding conservation law for a closed system w.r.t. that observer.
Now if our space-time has 3 symmetries w.r.t. an inertial observer namely isotropy and homogeneity of space and homogeneity of time, so only 3 conservation laws are possible in classical mechanics , namely conservation of angular momentum,momentum and energy of a closed system.

Aren't there more conservation laws possible ? What stops me from defining a quantity like $\vec{r} \cdot (\vec{r} $ **x** $ \vec{f})$ w.r.t. an inertial observer and take its derivative with time, and see when it is conserved w.r.t. time by equaing derivative to be $0$. If yes, how to find the corresponding symmetry ?

Comment: It isn't correct to say that a symmetry of spacetime corresponds to a conserved quantity. Noether's theorem tells us that the symmetry of the action corresponds to a conservation law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lagrangian mechanics, in view of celebrated Noether's theorem, if you have a Lagrangian invariant under the action of a one-parameter group of transformations, or weakly invariant (i.e. $\frac{\partial \cal L_\epsilon}{\partial \epsilon}|_\epsilon = \frac{df}{dt}$, where $\epsilon$ is the parameter of the group), then there exists a conserved quantity along the solutions of the equations of motion. These transformations are called (Lagrangian) **symmetries**.

I am precisely referring to transformations **acting on the coordinates of the points of matter of the physical system**. This action is next extended to velocities of these points by formally computing the $d/dt$ derivative (lifting the transformation to the first jet bundle, formally speaking).

The fundamental group of invariance of classical mechanics is **Galileo's (Lie) group**, $G$, that describes the transformations between coordinate of any pair of inertial systems:

$$t' = t+c\:,\qquad c\in \mathbb R$$
$${\bf x}' = R{\bf x} + t{\bf v} + {\bf c}\:, \qquad  R \in O(3)\:, {\bf v}, {\bf c}\in \mathbb R^3\:.$$

$G$ contains $10$ one-parameter (Lie) subgroups that must leave (weakly) invariant every Lagrangian  describing an isolated system  in an inertial reference system. Correspondingly there must exist 10 scalar conserved quantities. $6$ of them are induced by the Lie group of isometries of the 3D Euclidean space which, in fact has $6$ (Lie) one-parameter subgroups.

**All these symmetries are the same for every isolated mechanical system**.

Considering specific systems you can have further symmetries and associated conserved quantities. **However, in general, these Lagrangian symmetries  are not associated with symmetries of the classical spacetime,** but are proper of the mechanical system.

When you have a Larangian symmetry it is possible to prove that it transforms solutions of Eulero-Lagrange equations into solutions of Eulero-Lagrange equations. That is another notion of symmetry a **dynamical symmetry**.

**Lagrangian symmetries are dynamical symmetries but the converse is generally false**.

Moreover:

**Lagrangian symmetries imply the existence of conserved quantities but the converse generally is false**.

The correspondence instead is one-to-one if describing all this picture in Hamiltonian formulation and where the Hamiltonian symmetries are assumed to be canonical transformations:

**Hamiltonian symmetry** $\Leftrightarrow$ **Dynamical symmetry** $\Leftrightarrow$ **conserved quantity**

Comment: Could you explain the sentence: "Lagrangian symmetries imply the existence of conserved quantities but the converse generally is false"? I thought that in general one tries to determine what the conserved quantities of nature are, and then finds an action that has those symmetries as well. In other words, I was under the impression that the conserved quantities observed in nature do constrain the Lagrangian to incorporate the corresponding symmetries.

Comment: It depends on how you define the notion of symmetry for a Lagrangian. For instance the conservation of Runge vector for the Lagrangian of a point subjected to Coulombian potential cannot be induced by any geometric symmetry in space, extended to velocities by formal time derivation (the standard lift on a jet bundle). A more complicated notion can however be used (as a matter of fact a non-geometrical canonical transformation in Hamiltonian representation).

Comment: In Hamiltonian formulation (or quantum theories) instead everything is, in a sense, much more trivial: The conserved quantity is the generator of the (canonical) transformation leaving invariant in form the Hamiltonian that, in turn, gives rise to the conservation of that quantity.

Comment: (+1) Thanks for your answer. I was indeed (subconsciously) thinking about quantum field theories.

Comment: All this is a bit advanced for me right now. I will revisit this later.  So in short the total number of symmetries of the action in classical mechanics is ?

Comment: For an isolated system in an inertial reference frame the number  is $10$. Further symmetries may also appear, but depend on the specific system you are considering.